# ¿Cómo convertir un arraylist<Double> a array Float[]?

Tags: java, android, double, float

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo:

```
Arraylist<Double> datoDouble = new Arraylist<>();
datoDouble.add(2.33);
datoDouble.add(8.88);
Float[] datoFloat = Float[dato.size];
for(int i; i<= datoFloat.size;i++)
{
  datoFloat[i] = datoDouble;
}
```

Quiero convertir ese contenido a tipo `Float[]`, pero me marca un error diciendo que no es posible convertir `Double` a `Float`; también intenté convertir ese `Arraylist<Double>` a `String[]` y también me indica que No es posible convertir un `Double` a `String`.

BusquÉ en internet pero muestra cómo hacerlo con `float` y `double`, más no con `Float` y `Double`

Answer (score 1):

Tu código tiene algunos fallos:

- La clase correcta es ArrayList con la ele en mayúscula
- Cuando tratas con listas para comprobar su tamaño se usa el método size(), sin embargo para arrays se utiliza length.
- Te falta el new cuando creas el array de float.
- Te falta inicializar i a 0
- Cuando iteras una lista o un array que empieza desde cero, para comprobar si has llegado al final, tienes que utilizar "menor que" en lugar de "menor o igual" que. Sino el array o la lista se sale de límites al iterar.
- Para pasar de double a float lo puedes hacer con new.

Te pego el resultado de limpiar todos esos errores:

```
ArrayList<Double> datoDouble = new ArrayList<>();
datoDouble.add(2.33);
datoDouble.add(8.88);
Float[] datoFloat = new Float[datoDouble.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < datoFloat.length;i++) {
  datoFloat[i] = new Float(datoDouble.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Si note lode mis horrores ortográficos, igualmente muchas gracias, lo intentaré con tu método.

Comment: Si funcionó, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Inicializa el arreglo Float en base a la cantidadde elementos en el ArrayList

```
Float[] datoFloat = new Float[datoDouble.size()];
```

puedes agregar cada elemento dentro del Array Float conviertiendo cada elemento de `Double` a `Float` mediante `Float.parseFloat()`.

```
datoFloat[i] = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(datoDouble.get(i)));
```

Este sería el código :

```
    ArrayList<Double> datoDouble = new ArrayList<>();
    datoDouble.add(2.33);
    datoDouble.add(8.88);
    Float[] datoFloat = new Float[datoDouble.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < datoDouble.size(); i++)
    {
        datoFloat[i] = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(datoDouble.get(i)));
    }
```

Comment: Si me funciono. gracias por tu ayuda.